# Does Play 2.0 disable the catch-all route usage which is provided in 1.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Play 1.x provided a catch-all route in `conf/route`:

```
# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

But it seems that Play 2.x removed this feature.

Answer (score 3):

In general this change is step in the `type-safe` direction of whole 2.0 idea and I don't think it's wrong.

In frameworks with `type-safe` routing - like in Play 2 links are important part of logic, therefore using 'unknown' destinations would rise the errors prone and lower security in the same time, which isn't good deal. What's more in opposition to 1.2 new `router` validates parameters types which additionally improves application's quality, although it's required to write one more line for each `action`.

Finally there is always some possibility to add custom 'dispatcher' method in your class and 'catch' the multisegment path with `asterisk rule` (single params are identified with colon):

```
GET   /multi/*path    controllers.Application.mySubRouter(path)
```

this will pass whole part of the link after `http://domain.tld/multi/` and send to dispatcher action as a `String` so you can use it to split the segments by slash and use two first elements as controller and action names that you want to redirect to.

```
http://domain.tld/multi/MyController/myAction/p1/p2
```

However in such case I would definitely **recommend** to incorporate some additional validation for the allowed combinations in your dispatcher (maybe by custom DB rules-set or some regexp or something else) in other case you'll back to the entry point of my argumentation: `error prone` + `low security`

Answer (score 0):

You might find the onRouteRequest method on GlobalSettings which allows you to intercept route requests. Documentation is [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaInterceptors)